# What are the corresponding Django form classes rendered by default for each Google App Engine data entity?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Django lays out the mapping of Django model data types to Django form widgets nicely [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types), but I can't find a similar mapping for Google App Engine data types.  For instance what does a `db.TextProperty()` map too and how would I know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's documented in the source, starting [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/djangoforms.py#40).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a straight answer, but it seems that you can use that list you provided as a reference for the mapping.  According to the doc of [djangoforms](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html) from GAE:

> In most cases, you can use
>   db.djangoforms.ModelForm in the same
>   manner as the Django framework.

You can also infer from the [list of Property Classes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html) in how each one of them map to a corresponding form field.